# Keyboard, mouse and touchpad not working everytime booting the linux

Tags: boot, kali-linux, login, keyboard, mouse

Keyboard and mouse do not work after booting Linux. First, the keyboard is working when I turn on my laptop and enter the password for my sata. Then it will enter grub to choose the Os and the keyboard is working too I can choose if I use Linux or recovery mode. However, after the boot-up I can't use the keyboard to enter the user listed on my login before using Linux I can't even move the mouse so I can not log in and use Linux.

Comment: I found a solution while updating the os and some errors appeared. I made some research and found this: https://www.thetqweb.com/hacking/linux/fix-problem-has-occurred-and-the-system-cant-recover-in-linux/ and it works again after a month